# Defining the default id type for all domain classes

Tags: grails, grails-orm, id-generation, gorm-mongodb

In a mongo-only setup we need to use a `String id` (or ObjectId):

```
class SomeDomain {
  String id
  ///
}
```

in all domain classes of the app.

Is there a config shortcut to set the default `String id` overriding GORM's default `Long id` for all domain classes?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way that I know of other than by defining this in a base class or trait, e.g.

```
trait Persistent {
  String id
}

class SomeDomain implements Persistent {
  // other persistent properties
}
```